# Why can't I use __declspec(dllexport) to export DllGetClassObject() from a COM DLL?

Tags: c++, com, name-decoration

I am developing a COM dll and trying to export the DllGetClassObject() method with the **__declspec(dllexport)**.

Here is my declaration:

```
extern "C" HRESULT __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, 
                                                             REFIID riid, void** ppv)
```

But I kept get this error:

```
error C2375: 'DllGetClassObject' : redefinition; different linkage
```

So I try to check all the occurrence of the DllGetClassObject definitions. Thus found the following one in the **ObjBase.h**.

```
STDAPI  DllGetClassObject(__in REFCLSID rclsid, __in REFIID riid, __deref_out LPVOID FAR* ppv);
```

the STDAPI turns out to be like this:

```
#define STDAPI                  EXTERN_C HRESULT STDAPICALLTYPE
```

in other words, it's like this:

```
#define STDAPI                  extern "C" HRESULT __stdcall
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d(v=VS.80).aspx):

> To export functions, the
>   __declspec(dllexport) keyword must appear to the left of the
>   calling-convention keyword, if a
>   keyword is specified.

But my declaration mentioned before just didn't work.

### So does COM DLL *have to* export their methods with a *def* file?

---

### Update 1

I tested my declaration with a different method name, shown as below:

```
extern "C" HRESULT __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall f()
{
    return S_OK;
}
```

And this method was exported successfully. So these specifiers could be used together. It seems the Visual C++ compiler takes **STDAPI** and **extern "C" HRESULT __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall** as not compatible.

Comment: Did you try just using the macros? I.e. `__declspec(dllexport) STDAPI DllGetClassObject(...);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that. No compiling errors now. But no exports either. I double checked with DLL Exports Viewer and dumpbin.exe. It's such a dilemma. Is this one of the nasty bugs of Microsoft?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem occurs I think because a __stdcall function (for 32-bit builds) is normally  decorated with a underscore prefix and an `@count` postfix.  But if the function is also marked as `__declspec(dllexport)` additional decorations are added (`__imp`, I think).

You might be able to avoid using a .def file with the following pragma, if you're willing to live with the pragma (I think I'd go for the .def file):

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/export:DllGetClassObject=_DllGetClassObject@12" )
```

Note that for an x64 build, you might have to conditionally compile the pragma, which I think would be:

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/export:DllGetClassObject" )
```

Comment: That's it~ Thanks Michael.  :)

Comment: @Michael, doing this the DLL will have 2 exports for each function  `DllGetClassObject` and `_DllGetClassObject@12` (at least is what I can see with Dependency Walker). Is there a way to have exported only `DllGetClassObject` ?

Comment: Note that COM expects an unmangled name to be exported in the first place (so no name mangling is needed inside a .def file).

Comment: I think now with VS2022, this doesn't work for COM exports anymore. You get error `LNK4104: export of symbol 'symbol' should be PRIVATE`, which I think requires a def file to do. So I use a def file for COM exports, and `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` for other exports, because it's easier to manage.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't compile because the original declaration in objbase.h didn't have the __declspec(dllexport) attribute.  You cannot add it in the definition.  Won't help anyway, the name decoration isn't appropriate.  Michael showed you what to do about that.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I really appreciate your answers to my questions. Not just this one.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say yes.

Even Visual Studio 2008 automatically generates the .def file for ATL COM .dll projects.